# Add custom external link to menu

Tags: menus

I have added few custom external links to my menu and they all link to 1 website but with a few subfolders, so the urls look pretty much like this:

```
website.co.uk/web1/web2/web3/folder1\folder2\folder3
```

It does not seem to work for me as wordpress changes my site url every time when I click on it to something like this:

```
website.co.uk/web1/web2/web3/folder1folder2folder3
```

(so it removes back slashes from the url)

Of course the website opens but there is no content because such a folder does not exist.

Does anyone know a solution to this little problem?

Comment: I've never seen a website with backwards slashes. Did you try using all forward slashes?

Comment: Yes. I did try that and it link to the website but it does not show any content. I figured this is down to the website providers (we bought CAFM solution from that company) so I backed the question to them. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes (`\`) are not usually used in URL addresses, so WordPress tries to fix it to correct URL.

I’m almost certain that you should use slashes (`/`) instead:

```
http://website.co.uk/web1/web2/web3/folder1/folder2/folder3
```

Then it should all work correctly.